# Network program blocking

Tags: c#, debugging, networking

I am working on a network project which uses TCPListener and TCPClient. I have two almost identical instances of my program running on two different computers, but for some reason one of the instances works fine while the other one blocks somewhere.

What I'm wondering is if there is any way to debug what exactly is going on inside. The problem being that breakpoints don't work since they just show the execution of one thread and nothing else. I tried Pausing the program and it shows me the line Application.Run (...) and I have no way of getting in.

Debugging this is a nightmare, and any advice would be appreciated.

PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the toolbar of Visual Studio, you have a dropdown list with the threads. You can use this to switch to the current halting point in another thread after pausing the execution.

MSDN: [How to: Switch to Another Thread While Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157786.aspx)

Comment: I've been to that window, I see the worker threads I made but the Main thread just shows Application.Run and I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: double click on the worker threads until you see one that has a stack trace that is inside your code. double click on the stack level that is inside your code and that will show you where you are blocking.